# What's wrong with this `INSERT... SELECT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a system to interface our online gift card system with our brick-and-mortar gift cards.

My query:

```
INSERT INTO db1.giftcard (code, balance) 
    SELECT VoucherNumber, Balance FROM db2.Voucher b
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = b.Balance;
```

As it is, this query will essentially clone all the rows from `db2` into `db1`. It seems to me that the query is never encountering "duplicate keys", though I can't figure out why.

Comment: If `code` is the primary key, and `db2` is empty, why do you expect there to be any duplicates?

Comment: `entity_id` is the primary key, and `db2` isn't empty. The whole point is to update `db1.balance` with values from `db2`.

Comment: You need to make `code` a unique key if you want the expected behavior you describe

Comment: I've tried running `ALTER TABLE db1.giftcard ADD UNIQUE (code);` before I run my query, but that threw `Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'code'` and gave me a chance to stop the query. We're working on a live DB, so I was told to stop the query and go back to the drawing board. If I let it run, would that fix the problem? Or should I look at making code a UNIQUE in the schema? I'm not opposed to that. It would make sense, considering we can't have duplicate gift card codes.